# Populating a list with a variable amount of images in Python

Tags: python, list

I read the number of image files in a folder and assign that value to say `fnum`.
Then I want to add these images to a list.

I first get the images by using:

```
import os
fnum = int(len(os.listdir("Photos")))
i = 1
for n in range(fnum):
    globals()["my_img" + str(i)] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Photos/Picture"+ str(i) + "_Thumbnail.JPG"))
    i += 1
```

Things are okay to this point.

For example if `fnum` is 6 then I can do this by:

```
image_list = [my_img1, my_img2, my_img3, my_img4, my_img5, my_img6]
```

but I want to be able to do this for a general case to cover:

```
image_list = [my_img1, my_img2, ....., my_img(fnum)]
```

I tried this:

```
image_list = []
for i in range(1, fnum):
   image_list.append(my_img + (i))
   i += 1
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for something like this, without any of that `globals()` malarkey:

```
import glob

images = []

for path in glob.glob("Photos/Picture*Thumbnail.JPG"):
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    images.append(image)
```

You can then access each `PhotoImage` object with `images[0]`, `images[1]`, etc., or loop over them with `for image in images:`.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only adding new "my_img" + number to list you can use append or adding lists:

```
#Your code (I am assuming it works)
import os
fnum = int(len(os.listdir("Photos")))
i = 1
for n in range(fnum):
    globals()["my_img" + str(i)] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Photos/Picture"+ str(i) + "_Thumbnail.JPG"))
    i += 1


#Code which uses append
fnum = 6
image_list = []
for i in range(1, fnum):
   image_list.append("my_img" + str(i))
#print (image_list)


#Code which uses append
fnum = 6
image_list = []
for i in range(1, fnum):
   image_list.append("my_img" + str(i))
#print (image_list)


#Change list with names of variables to list with values of these variables
image_list = [globals()[variableName] for image in image_list]
print(image_list)
```

Quciknote: while you're using for i in range you dont need to increase I by yourself. Range cretaes lists like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., fnum] and picking each value from this list for each iteration.

### EDIT:

I've added line which converts list of names to list of values to code above.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I can get it to work for the hardwired case:

Comment: If I do the hardwired case with 6 photos - image_list = [my_img1, my_img2, my_img3, my_img4, my_img5, my_img6]
#image_list = [my_img(i), for i = 1, fnum]
print(image_list) I get the print [<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000017E3150FFD0>, <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000017E33640220>, <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000017E3150FE20>, <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000017E3364B790>, <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000017E3364B8E0>, <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000017E3364B9A0>]
>>>

Comment: But if I use your version I get
['my_img1', 'my_img2', 'my_img3', 'my_img4', 'my_img5'] for the print of what is in image_list

Comment: @Bill Well, looks like i didn't fully understood your problem. =)
However, I've updated my answer, due to fact, that converting list of names to list of values is only one line of code